# Stop SSH password prompts in serverspec

Tags: ruby, net-ssh, serverspec

I'm in an environment with authentication tokens, so typically a SSH password is not required. My serverspec tests are always asking me for a password. Is there a way to prevent this?

No password required:

```
$ ssh atlspf01
newatson@atlspf01:~$
```

Yet, in serverspec

```
$ rake spec
Password:
```

Relevant code in spec_helper.rb

```
require 'serverspec'
require 'net/ssh'

set :backend, :ssh
...
set :host, ENV['TARGET_HOST']
set :ssh_options, :user => ENV['USERNAME']
```

UPDATE: Problem is that net::ssh does not support Kerberos authentication (gssapi-with-mic). Use ssh::ssh::kerberos or use ssh keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your configuration, you only pass info about user to `ssh_options`

Assuming that your target host is stored into environmental variable `TARGET_HOST` and username is stored into `USERNAME`, you should do something like this:

`set :ssh_options, Net::SSH::Config.for(ENV['TARGET_HOST']).merge(user: ENV['USERNAME'])`

Comment: It connects to the correct host as it is. It's the password prompts I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @neil Using the above answer, does it still require password or does it complain about sudo password?

Comment: With the above answer I still get the prompt 'Password:'. I think it's for SSH because if I provied the wrong password I get an SSH authentication failure.

Comment: @neil what is the output of `Net::SSH::Config.for(ENV['TARGET_HOST'])` ? At my system, I get something like this: {:auth_methods=>["none", "publickey", "password", "keyboard-interactive"], :send_env=>[/^LANG$/, /^LC_CTYPE$/, /^LC_NUMERIC$/, /^LC_TIME$/, /^LC_COLLATE$/, /^LC_MONETARY$/, /^LC_MESSAGES$/]} and serverspec works without asking me for a password. So I guess you should check the auth_methods.

Comment: looks the same as yours: `{:auth_methods=>["none", "publickey", "password", "keyboard-interactive"], :send_env=>[/^LANG$/, /^LC_CTYPE$/, /^LC_NUMERIC$/, /^LC_TIME$/, /^LC_COLLATE$/, /^LC_MONETARY$/, /^LC_MESSAGES$/]}`

Comment: @neil btw, are you sure that username is stored in `USERNAME` and not `USER` environment variable ? Also, try adding `puts "ssh options: #{Specinfra::Configuration.ssh_options}"` at the end of spec/spec_helper.rb so as to verify that everything is actually set correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80589/discussion-between-neil-h-watson-and-egwspiti).